# A z3c.form calendar widget that works on overlays?

Tags: plone

I need a calendar widget for a z3c.form's Date field that works with overlays.

I've tested `collective.z3cform.datetimewidget`. It works in normal forms, but  the calendar widget doesn't appear inside overlays. Same thing with `jyu.z3cform.datepicker`; it doesn't work with overlays.  `collective.z3cform.datepicker` has problems with the date format and it seems it's in early stages of development.

Does Plone has any calendar widget for Date fields that works in overlays?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JavaScript support for the widget is not being loaded. On standalone pages that use the widget, this is handled semi-automatically — but not when the widget is loaded in an overlay.

Just visit the portal_javascripts tool in the Zope Management Interface, and enable the **plone.app.jquerytools.dateinput.js** support globally. You'll need to also enable its css in portal_css.

Comment: They seem to be active:  <javascript authenticated="False" cacheable="True" compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True" expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.dateinput.js" inline="False"/>
 and  <stylesheet title="" applyPrefix="False" authenticated="False" cacheable="False" compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True" expression=""  id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.dateinput.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" rendering="import"/>
I'm making the tests in development mode.